# How to apply different aggregation functions to different columns and give the results different names?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

Let us assume that we have a pandas data frame with the following columns: `group`, 'val1', `val2`. Now I want to group by using the column called `group`. Then, as a result, I would like to have a table with the following columns:

1. Minimum (for the group) of the columns `val1`. I want to call this column `min_val1`
2. Sum of the value (for the group) from the columns `val1`. I want to call this columns `sum_val1`
3. Number of distinct values in the columns `val2`. I want to call this columns `distinct_val2`.

Can I do something like that:

```
df.groupby('group', as_index=False).agg({
    'min_val1' : lambda x : min(x['val_1']), 
    'sum_val1' : lambda x : sum(x['val1']),
    'distinct_val2' : lambda x : distinct(x['val2'])
})
```

The above given code does not work, but is there something similar that would work?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the syntax, I think you want `df.groupby('group', as_index=False).agg({
    'val1' : [np.min, np.sum]
    'val2' : lambda x : distinct(x)
})` also any reason you're not accepting past answers to questions you've posted? If the answers don't satisfy your question you should comment/update your posts to state why. This is to stop a build up of unanswered questions

Comment: @EdChum, in the solution that you provided there is no way to control the names of the new columns. This is what I am missing. Concerning the accepting the answers. I do it but maybe with some delay.

Comment: The column naming part is something that is missing unfortunately, it's probably already an improvement issue on github, you'd have to rename the columns after the aggregation or do the column naming/agg one col at a time I think

Comment: You can get this with a dictionary of dictionaries: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9052